# Playwright Test - work in 4 browsers(Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Firefox, Webkit), toggle button problems

Tags: typescript, cross-browser, playwright, webautomation, playwright-test

The test passes successfully for Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers and gives an error for Firefox and Webkit browsers. When running the same test at the same time.

Gives this error:

```
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
        element is not stable - waiting...
      element is visible, enabled and stable
      scrolling into view if needed
      done scrolling
      performing click action
      <div class="react-switch-handle"></div> intercepts pointer events
    retrying click action, attempt #138
      waiting 500ms
 waiting 500ms
      waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
        element is not stable - waiting...
      element is visible, enabled and stable
      scrolling into view if needed
      done scrolling
      performing click action
      <div class="breadcrumb">…</div> intercepts pointer events
    retrying click action, attempt #137
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1rwi.png) - this toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that there is a div with a class `breadcrumb` that is fully (or partially) covering the element your are trying to click on.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but look at the image, this element (breadcrumb) is (Configuration -> System -> Mapping), does not overlap the element I want to click on.
And why in Chrome and Edge work, but Firefox and Webkit don't?

Comment: Maybe your selector is not specific enough and it's picking another element under a breadcrumb?

Comment: I tried all possible selectors, when using them, the test does not pass on any of the 4 browsers